# Wordpress Menu Parent Link as label

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

once again it's me :) I set up a new wordpress site using foundation5. To get it up fast I used the navwalker which mirzap kindly provided. 
https://gist.github.com/mirzap/4046020

I am now trying to display the parent items as label so instead of the normal output in my offcanvas.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Parent Item</a><li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First Child</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Second Child</a><li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Parent Item</a><li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child Item</a><li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="#">No Child Item</a><li>
</li>
```

I want the output like this

```
<ul>
    <li><label>Parent Item</label></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First Child</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second Child</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><label>Parent Item</a></label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="#">No Child Item</a></li>
</li>
```

C'mon this cant be this hard in wordpess; I'm just overseeing something, right?

Comment: Use the `$depth` argument in the walker to check if you're on top level items (depth of 0) and adjust the output accordingly. You may want to switch `label` with `span` by the way. Label isn't appropriate where you're attempting to use it.

Comment: @NathanDawson thank you for your help, but I couldnt figure out how to, tried a lot now.... could you give an example please? And I didnt understand what you mean with the span - I'm sticking to the foundation example code

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Parent Item</label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">First Child</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Parent Item</a></label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">No Child Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is how the html should look like. As your inner UL's are just element of LI's.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake - thank you @NathaDawson! If anyone else searching for the solution, you just have to add two lines of code.

From

```
$item_output  = $args->before;
$item_output .= (!in_array('section', $classes)) ? '<a'.$attributes.'>' : '';
$item_output .= $args->link_before.apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID);
$item_output .= $args->link_after;
$item_output .= (!in_array('section', $classes)) ? '</a>' : '';
$item_output .= $args->after;
```

TO

```
$item_output  = $args->before;
if( 0 != $depth ) $item_output .= (!in_array('section', $classes)) ? '<a'.$attributes.'>' : '';
if( 0 == $depth ) $item_output .= (!in_array('section', $classes)) ? '<label>' : '';
$item_output .= $args->link_before.apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID);
$item_output .= $args->link_after;
if( 0 != $depth ) $item_output .= (!in_array('section', $classes)) ? '</a>' : '';
if( 0 == $depth ) $item_output .= (!in_array('section', $classes)) ? '</label>' : '';
$item_output .= $args->after;
```

As you can see, I only ask, if it's depth 0 and if it is, I set an label instead of the a. That's it. Thank you guys! You're awesome!